# WCF POST service with WebInvokeBodyStyle as wrapped not working as expected

Tags: wcf, rest, post, httpwebrequest, http-post

I have created a WCF POST service with below mentioned signature. This is hosted successfully in IIS and I can see it in the service's help page as:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "TestMethod/{lang}/{str}/{selectedstring}/")]
    string TestMethod(string lang, string str, string selectedstring, string mylist, int testval);
```

On the service's help page the method shows correctly as

```
TestMethod/{lang}/{str}/{selectedstring}/ || POST || Service at http://localhost:86/MyRestService.svc/TestMethod/{LANG}/{STR}/{SELECTEDSTRING}/
```

I am trying to call this service using fiddler with below mentioned options (Based on a few look up on blogs):

Method: Post

URL -   'http://servername:86/MyRestService.svc/TestMethod/en-us/str1/qad11/'

Req. Headers:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: servername:86
Content-Type: application/xml

Request Body:

```
<TestMethod xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><mylist>string val</mylist><testval>3</testval></TestMethod>
```

However it always gives me an HTTP result code 411 (Length Required), the same error when I try to call the service from my .net test stub.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler should calculate the HTTP header named `Content-Length` for you (at least it does for v2.3.9.3) Check in the raw tab of the *request* for something like: `Content-Length: nnn` where nnn is the string length of the request body. If not, then you'll need to add it yourself. Also, you could try a browser plug-in like [the POSTMan chrome plug](https://github.com/a85/POSTMan-Chrome-Extension/wiki) to create your requests.

Comment: Fiddler is adding the content length header by it own, but thanks for introducing me to POSTMan chrome plugin.